# MediaStore get Image height/width

Tags: android, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I'm querying `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` and the query works fine. I'm able to get the data from every column that has a constant, for example:

```
currentImage.ImageUrl = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            currentImage.Lat = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));
            currentImage.Long = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE));
```

The width/height columns has no constant (no `MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH`) so I'm trying to access them with `imagecursor.getLong(imagecursor.getColumnIndex("width"));`.

Tried to use getLong, getString, getInt... nothing - always the same crash.

Here's the stack:

```
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED dat=file:///mnt/sdcard flg=0x10 } in com.Activity.android.chat.service.ChatService$ChatServiceReceiver@415b26c0
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:515)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:582)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:102)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.Activity.android.chat.service.ChatService.getUserImages(ChatService.java:251)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.Activity.android.chat.service.ChatService.access$1(ChatService.java:209)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.Activity.android.chat.service.ChatService$ChatServiceReceiver.onReceive(ChatService.java:204)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
02-22 19:38:26.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     ... 9 more
```

Would appreciate any help with this... have no idea what else can I try.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution (stupid mistake...):**

I didn't include the width and height columns in the projection... 
Can't understand why Google won't give them constants to avoid all this confusion but anyways, the solution was to add them.

```
final String[] columns = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE, MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE, "width", "height"
        };
```

Comment: I had the same problem and used this code. But it gives error: "no such column : width"... Would you please help me?

Comment: @Farid Ala Sure! I think "width" and "height" columns are only available on Android 3.0 and above so if you're trying to access them on lower Android versions, it'll give you the "no such column" error. You can check if you have these columns by opening the mediaStore Database using Root Explorer -> Data -> Data -> com.android.providers.media -> databases -> external.db -> images .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, it's only available on  Android 3.0+. So, How I can get images size on Android 3.0- ? Do I need to use the solution of Samir? As you mentioned, it's a bit expensive. I'm really confused.

Comment: @Farid Ala It's a little expensive but you can build your own object that holds all the images info, including the height and weight using Samir's code and only then populate the list (getView) with the new object. That way, the expensive operation will happen out side of the getView of the list adapter and The list will scroll smoother.

Comment: You are right. Actually my application uses AndEngine and I'm going to display images via Sprites. This thread, helped me a lot. Thanks:-)

Answer (score 5):

```
        try {
                    Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

                    int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
                    int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printstacktrace();
               }
```

Comment: Thanks but this operation it too expensive for what I'm doing... running on 1000 images and decoding each one is something I want to avoid, especially when the with and height columns exist in the mediastore.images DB

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't call [cursor.moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)
before accessing to the cursor's data.

Comment: I did... that's not it. Thanks though ;)